# How to create a GitHub Desktop repository with more folders each with its project

Tags: xcode, github, directory, github-desktop

When following steps:

```
GitHub Desktop/File/Add Local Repository/XYFolderWithXcodeproj
```

And the following steps via as per video "[Github Desktop Tutorial on a Mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYmnyi5eJ8E&t=221s)" starting from (2:32), I could create repository when the `XYFolderWithXcodeproj` folder did contain only one project.

However, in case the `XYFolderWithXcodeproj` folder does contain two folders each with its projects, the GitHub Desktop does initiate the repository that was already created months ago and with directory path only up to Documents folder.
(I did remove it, still is was not possible to remove it with having selected the option "`Also move this repository to Trash`".
When trying to do this, there was message: "Failed to move the repository directly to Trash. A common reason for this is that the directory or one of its files is open in another program.)

Would like to ask for advice what steps to follow to create a GitHub Desktop repository with more folders each with its project.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Failed to move the repository directly to Trash.  
> A common reason for this is that the directory or one of its files
> is open in another program
> ```

Then try and close GitHub Desktop, then, from a file Explorer, delete the local repository you do not need, and re-open GitHub Desktop.

Comment: Hi @VonC thing is that GitHub Desktop shows that "XYLocalRepository" is on directory "/Users/XYUser/Documents" while in real "XYLocalRepository" is on directory "...Documents/Course/Functions". There is only initial commit and around 3k changes. Sure do not want to commit to main all the files located in Documents folder. Strange is that this that this "XYLocalRepository" is shown only when trying to create repository with more folders each with its project.

Comment: @mairo Strange indeed. Is there any hidden .git folder in `/Users/XYUser/Documents`?

Comment: Thanks for tip @VonC I found one folder named GitHub within /Documents that was empty, anyhow did delete it. Now after trying to adding local repository with more projects, it was created (no issue as before) with possibility to Commit to main. After doing so there's error: "On branch main. Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'. Untracked files: (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
     Untitled/ nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)". No repository was created on GitHub.

Comment: @mairo " No repository was created on GitHub.": none will be visible on GitHub as long as you do not push anything. And you cannot commit without first adding files.

Comment: Yeah @VonC before when Adding Local Repository the system did prompt me to create also repository in which the folders with projects were already existent. Now it was not the case. How can I add files to repository? I tried via GitHub, only zip files were created (not possible to open via Xcode directly). Also tried from Xcode project via Remotes/Add Existing Remote and then Source Control/Commint and then Source Control/Push. There is an error: "The local repository is out of date. Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again".

Comment: @mairo It is best to initialize/manage the local repository through git command line first. Once it is working from command line, you can try and import it in XCode.